# Direct Product and Quotient of Groups

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces, direct-product

Quick (and basic) group theory question:

Say G, H, K some (Lie) groups, does it in general hold that 
$$ 
(G \times H)/H = G 
$$
and that
$$
H = K\times G   \to K = H / G
$$
And if so, does it then also hold that
$$
(H/G)/K = (H/K)/G 
$$
where throughout for simplicity I assume every time I take a quotient that the group I quotient by is a normal subgroup of the group that is quotiented and I defined "=" here as up to an isomorphism. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take homomorphism $G\times H \to G$ such that $(g,h)\to g$, then check it is onto and kernel is $H$ and use Isomorphism Theorem.

Second follows from first.

Third does not make sense unless we have subgroup relation among $H,G,K$ as you can define $G/H$ only if $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$